# Map 2 values in a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I have a list of dictionary "`list_dict`"

Input:

```
list_dict=[{'a':'a' ,'b':'b','c':'lala'},{'a':'a1','b':'b1','c':'lala1'}]
```

I need an output like this - All values corresponding to the key '`a`' and the values corresponding to the key '`b`' mapped into a list

```
 l1=['a-b','a1-b1']
```

This is what I have so far, Also if there is no key '`a`' in the dictionary it shouldn't throw and error. Just take it as null and proceed.

```
l1=[element['a'] for element in list_dict if 'a' in element]
```

Questions:
Can someone help me get the desired output?
How would one do it using lambda?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `dict`'s `get` method to prevent the `KeyError` if the keys are not present:

```
l1 = ['{}-{}'.format(element.get('a'), element.get('b')) for element in list_dict]
```

Using this input:

```
list_dict = [
    {'a':'a' ,'b':'b','c':'lala'},
    {'a':'a1','b':'b1','c':'lala1'},
    {'b':'b'}
]
```

Which results in:

```
['a-b', 'a1-b1', 'None-b']
```

Or, after another pass at reading your question you might be asking for something like this:

```
l1 = ['{}-{}'.format(element['a'], element['b'])
    for element in list_dict if 'a' in element and 'b' in element]
```

Which results in:

```
['a-b', 'a1-b1']
```

with the same input.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `lambda` as requested,

```
map(lambda x: '-'.join([x.get('a'), x.get('b')]), list_dict)

['a-b', 'a1-b1']
```

Answer (score 1):

With list comprehension:

```
l = [{'a':'a' ,'b':'b','c':'lala'},{'a':'a1','b':'b1','c':'lala1'}]
res = ['-'.join(v for k,v in d.items() if k in ('a','b')) for d in l]

print(res)
```

The output:

```
['a-b', 'a1-b1']
```